# Tango Unity Application example throws "Unfortunately, (app name) has stopped" when is built to Android device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango, tango

I tried to follow these tutorials below to build a Tango example project on a Lenovo Tango device:

https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/unity/unity-setup

https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/unity/unity-howto-motion-tracking

When I try to build, the application is built on the device but it crashes when I try to open it. In the Unity console, these two exceptions are thrown:

```
 ExitGUIException: Exception of type 'UnityEngine.ExitGUIException' was thrown.
UnityEngine.GUIUtility.ExitGUI () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/IMGUI/Managed/GUIUtility.cs:163)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSdkRoot.Browse (System.String sdkPath)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.GetInstance ()
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckAndroidSdk.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PrepareForBuild (BuildOptions options, BuildTarget target)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PrepareForBuild (BuildOptions options, BuildTarget target)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.PrepareForBuild (BuildOptions options, BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, BuildTarget target) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:87)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
```

and this:

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: Build failed with errors.
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x001b9] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:162 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (Boolean askForBuildLocation, BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00050] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:83 
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
```

I have followed all the steps in the tutorials above, downloaded all the required libraries and SDK. Anyone knows waht it could be?

My Unity version is 2017.10f3 Personal. Android SDK 17 and Lenovo Tango PB2-690Y with Android version 6.0.1

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tango's Unity SDK only works with Unity versions 5.2 - 5.6. It does not support 2017.1 or above.